# How to reference path to maven dependency file

Tags: java, maven, csv

I have a .csv file located within a maven dependency named quality.jar under com.quality.data with the name MASTER.csv

Is there a way to know the full path of MASTER.csv ? I am trying to insert into the below code:

```
new File(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource(<MASTER.csv>).toURI());
```

Comment: Try with full path - getResource("com/quality/data/MASTER.csv")

Comment: that doesn't seem to work

Comment: It would be better to do `getResourceAsStream("/com/quality/data/MASTER.csv")`, the `File` constructor will have trouble with a URI that points to inside a jar file.